# Informatica update strategy Query for pseudocode logic

Tags: transformation, lookup, informatica

A pseudo code logic for a particular update strategy transformation query is given. I need to write it in informatica update strategy Sql query. I am using an unconnected lookup transformation. As I am very new to this , I am unable to make an query for this logic.

```
If(record does not exists in target table)
If(dbcal is not set)
Insert 
Else
Reject
Else if(record  exists in target table)
If(dbcal is not set)
Update
Else
Delete
```

My logic is like
    iif((isnull(recordname),iif(isnull(dbcal),dd_insert)),
    dd_update, dd_delete)

Please suggest a valid query. TIA

Comment: The else if part does not make sense to me. How would you update or delete, if the record does not exist in target table?

Comment: From a maintenance perspective, putting everything into one update strategy means you wont know how many of the transactions were update, insert or delete when you check the session logs. A better practise is to use a router with 3 separate groups for update delete and insert with logic for separating the groups in the router... thats my 2 cents

Comment: The logic is updated @Samik

Comment: This is one my assignment question wherein I have just come across lookup and update strategy. @Daniel Machet

Answer (score 0):

Ah well then, much as I love homework... good luck

Answer (score 0):

Based on you pseudo code, it should be something like below.

```
iif(isnull(recordname),
  iif(isnull(dbcal),
    dd_insert,
    dd_reject), 
  iif(isnull(dbcal),
    dd_update, 
    dd_delete)
)
```